# How can I make 3 different menus?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I need to do an Agenda in Drupal 7. The table for the events is more or less already done, but I would need to add 3 days on the top like:

Day 1   -    Day 2     -    Day 3

Depending on which day is clicked, it will show an agenda or the other.

How can I do this?

I'm adding the content using the *Agenda* content type I created, but I would need to create content for those 3 days.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It sounds like you might be able to use [Views Menu Tabs](https://www.urbaninsight.com/article/views-menu-tabs-quick-guide) or the [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.

Comment: I would create a Taxonomy named "Days" with the terms Day 1, Day 2, Day 3. Then add a Taxonomy field so you can assign which day an Agenda Node belongs to. You can then use one of the modules @hotwebmatter suggested.

Comment: Yep @RyanHartman, that sounds like it could work. Add a _Taxonomy term reference_ field to the node bundle for the custom _Agenda_ entity type. Then use that field to tag content for inclusion on each of the three tabs for Day 1, Day 2, Day 3.

Comment: Thank you guys! Thats what I did. I didn't know how to add the menus but once I could do that, I realized on how to filter with taxonomy terms (I added them first to the vocabulary). I'm getting used to Drupal at least in a basic way.

By the way, on the Agenda I made (as a table format) is it possible to modify its css style? Do you know how? If it's necessary I could make another thread.

Thank you again!

Comment: You certainly can. Drupal has an entire theme system so yes you can do so, but that is off-topic for this discussion.

Comment: @Ray91 the whole trick to adding CSS and JS to a custom theme is accomplished in Drupal by using libraries. So make a subtheme of your current theme so you can modify it, then tell it where to find CSS by editing `mytheme.libraries.yml`. At this stage, you don't need to learn about Twig templates or anything. You should be able to add some CSS to modify your tables

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to utilize the **Taxonomy** module.

1. In your case, setup a new taxonomy with the name *Agenda Days*.
2. Add some of your terms to it: *Day 1*, *Day 2*, *Day 3*, etc.
3. Go back to your *Agenda* content type and add a taxonomy term reference field, configured to point at your new *Agenda Days* taxonomy.
4. Edit your content and select which Day they belong to.
5. Install and enable either the [Views Menu Tabs](https://www.urbaninsight.com/article/views-menu-tabs-quick-guide) or the [Quick Tabs](https://www.urbaninsight.com/article/views-menu-tabs-quick-guide) module.
6. Edit your view and add your new taxonomy field.
7. Set the views display mode to one provided by the module you selected, configured to use your taxonomy field for sorting.